# How to send email with multiple attachments using this code

Tags: powershell

I don't know much about PowerShell, but I found this code here in Stack Overflow on how to send an e-mail with an attachment. I was wondering if it would be possible to change it a little bit so I can send two attachments instead of one. I would like to send the files without using ZIP or RAR to compress:

Attachments:
"C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\impressora.txt"
"C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\impressora2.txt"

```
$Username = "myemail@sapo.pt";
$Password = "mypassword";
$path = "C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\impressora.txt";

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string]$attachmentpath){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
    $message.From = "myemail@sapo.pt";
    $message.To.Add($email);
    $message.Subject = "Hello how are you";
    $message.Body = "Is this really going to happen?????";
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($attachmentpath);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment);

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sapo.pt", "587");
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true;
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.send($message);
    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
    $attachment.Dispose();
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email "myfriend@yahoo.com.br" -attachmentpath $path;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array of strings for the `-attachmentpath` parameter by using `[string[]]`. You can also leave out the step of creating a separate `Net.Mail.Attachment` object since that is already incorporated in the base `Net.Mail.MailMessage` object you already have.

Example:

```
$Username = "myemail@sapo.pt"
$Password = "mypassword"
$path = "C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\impressora.txt","C:\Users\ricar\Desktop\impressora2.txt"

function Send-ToEmail([string]$email, [string[]]$attachmentpath){

    $message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $message.From = "myemail@sapo.pt"
    $message.To.Add($email)
    $message.Subject = "Hello how are you"
    $message.Body = "Is this really going to happen?????"
    $attachmentpath | foreach {$message.Attachments.Add($_)}

    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.sapo.pt", "587")
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)
    $smtp.send($message)
    write-host "Mail Sent"  
 }
Send-ToEmail  -email "myfriend@yahoo.com.br" -attachmentpath $path
```

Also, there's no need to include the semicolon at the end of each line in PowerShell. I would only use them if it fits in with the current code style guidelines.